# What is the meaning of "political affiliation" when you register to vote?

Tags: united-states, parties, political-system, voter-registration

When you register to vote, one of the boxes you have to check is one for "party affiliation".

What is the meaning of "party affiliation"? Does it mean that one is "locked" into voting for the party he/she is affiliated to?

Could it have different meanings in different states?

Comment: The other question's answers cover it well. Super short version: In states with "closed primaries", registration determines whether you get the Republican or Democrat ballot in a primary.